# finding the summation of $\sum_{\ell=k}^n \binom{\ell}{k}$

Tags: summation, combinations

$$\sum_{\ell=k}^n \binom{\ell}{k} =
 \binom{n+1}{k+1}$$

Can someone explain how we got that equation? Expanding it we get

$$\binom{k}{k} + \binom{k+1}{k} + \binom{k+2}{k} + .....+ \binom{n}{k}$$

but how does that add up to  $$\binom{n+1}{k+1}$$

Comment: Yes it's a duplicate, but I had no idea it was called the Hockey-Stick Identity.

Comment: Then you should've closed it as a duplicate yourself rather than waiting for us to do it for you.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know I could do that.

Comment: While a duplicate is pending, it should appear at the top of your question "This may answer your question... " and you'll have the option of "yes, this answers my question" or "no, my question is different".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : Rewrite $$\binom{k}{k} =\binom{k+1}{k+1}$$

And now use the identity $$\binom{k}{r}+\binom{k}{r+1}=\binom{k+1}{r+1}$$